# Extra space in cucumber step when using to_s(:long)

Tags: ruby-on-rails, cucumber, capybara

I have a step that fails with the following...

```
expected #has_content?("July  4, 2009") to return true, got false
```

The problem, I think, is the extra space between "July" and "4".  I am using published_on.to_s(:long) in both the step definition and the view, so I'm not entirely sure where the extra space is coming from.

Any ideas?

Comment: Show us the step and its definition please.

Comment: Here are the step definitions --> https://gist.github.com/b6ba990085532c6d05bf

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's what happens when you try:

```
Date.civil(2010, 7, 4).strftime("%e") # => " 4"
```

And Rails uses `%e` in their `:long` [format](https://github.com/rails/rails/blob/master/activesupport/lib/active_support/core_ext/date/conversions.rb#L8). The funny thing is that `%e` isn't [documented](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core/classes/Time.html#M000298).

I would adjust my step definition to match Ruby behavior if you don't care about the extra space (extra spaces won't show in HTML anyway). If you do care about it, squish it:

```
Date.civil(2010, 7, 4).to_s(:long).squish # => "July 4, 2010"
```

Squish is avaiable in Rails 3. If you're using Rails 2, you can use gsub:

```
Date.civil(2010, 7, 4).to_s(:long).gsub(/\s+/, " ") # => "July 4, 2010"
```

Comment: Yup, cucumber (just like browsers) ignores repeated HTML, so even though in the source the date has 2 spaces, cucumber only sees it as one.

Answer (score 0):

I ran into the same problem with my cucumber test today!

The problem (as iain pointed out) is that `Date::DATE_FORMATS[:long]` is `"%B %e, %Y"`. The `%e`, according to `ri strftime`, yields a **blank-padded** day number:

```
  %d - Day of the month, zero-padded (01..31)
          %-d  no-padded (1..31)
  %e - Day of the month, blank-padded ( 1..31)
```

So by default, this is what I see in Rails 3.1.3:

```
> d = '2012-02-01'.to_date
=> Wed, 01 Feb 2012

> d.to_s(:long)
=> "February  1, 2012"
```

Strangely, Rails uses a different day format for the `:long` format of *times* (`%d`, which yields `"01"`) as for *dates* (`%e`, which yields `" 1"`):

```
> d = '2012-02-01'.to_time
=> 2012-02-01 00:00:00 UTC

> d.to_s(:long)
=> "February 01, 2012 00:00"

> Time::DATE_FORMATS[:long]
=> "%B %d, %Y %H:%M"

> Date::DATE_FORMATS[:long]
=> "%B %e, %Y"
```

**The solution** then is to use **`"%-d"`** for the day in your format string instead of `%e`:

```
> Date::DATE_FORMATS[:long] = "%B %-d, %Y"
=> "%B %-d, %Y"

> d = '2012-02-01'.to_date
Wed, 01 Feb 2012

> d.to_s(:long)
=> "February 1, 2012"
```

You can just add this line to a new initializer, `config/initializers/date_formats.rb`:

```
Date::DATE_FORMATS[:long] = "%B %-d, %Y"
```

Please comment on https://github.com/rails/rails/pull/1994 if you would like to see this default changed in Rails.

Answer (score 0):

For what it's worth, I would rather use the `"%-d"` fix (or even `"%-e"`! which gives the same results) than `".squish"`, which is Rails-specific, and not as portable (why not use the Ruby-native `".squeeze"`, or even `".squeeze(' ')"` at that then, if you don't want to mess around with the date formats?).

Also, as an update: @iain mentions that '%e' isn't documented. For what it's worth, [it is now](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-2.0/Time.html#method-i-strftime)! (although interestingly, not `"%-e"` specifically, which, if you do try it, is valid, and works!)